# Is it possible for an air application to switch to other running applications on windows?

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, air

i need to make an application ( multiplatform, MacOS and Windows ) which has to be able to switch to another running application on the same computer.
Because of the multiplatform demand i choose to produce a self-contained adobe air application.

On MacOS i can call a script to use the native application-switcher from within my application. 
for example:

```
tell application "XYZ" to set visible of every process whose visible is true and name is not "XYZ" to false
```

Can i achieve the same thing with e.g. a batch file on Windows?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can. But as you mentioned you'll have to create two files for this job and then call the appropriate one depending on the system.

Comment: Would you call this using the Native Process API? If so, I'm pretty sure you will have to compile the application down to a native executable .exe / .dmg which could, potentially, render the idea of cross platform redundant.